# Postgres Script: Find Employees not in the same Location as Manager permisson

Tags: sql, postgresql, scripting

Hi Im trying to get the following result below

We have three tables Employee, Permission, and Reporting(manager)

[image]

Supposed to be managers should only be assigned to employees in locations that they have permission too but this isn't what happening. The reporting table overides this and we must get the employees

Here's the result we need either of the two

[image]

Basically the result must show the employees that are assigned to managers even though the managers don't have permission to the employees locations. eg. (Employee 1 is assigned as manager of employee 21 even though employee 1 doesn't have manager permission for location 25)

I'm having a hard time with the conditions to join the three table the produce the results we need

Comment: Why does manager 1 (ideal result) only have 21 ? Why not 21 22 23 24 ? I think you missed another table...

Comment: Please update your question to remove images and replace them with formatted text. See [Why not upload images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). You can create formatted tables via [Senseful Solutions](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/). Paste the results between lines containing only **```**. Better yet create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).